# NodeJS - How to store image dimension in a variable

Tags: node.js, sharp

I am trying to store the image dimension (width, height) in a variable in Nodejs.

for reference
https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/776

```
const metaReader = sharp()
metaReader
  .metadata()
  .then(info => {
    // info object contains the image dimension. how to return this object
    console.log(info)
})
let metainfo = stream.pipe(metaReader)
```

Comment: It seems like an object you can use a global variable for this to return the value info and store it. Just add a return instead of console.log() and store the info in a variable

Answer (score 0):

Can try this code instead?

```js
let image;
const metaReader = sharp()
metaReader
  .metadata()
  .then(info => {
    // info object contains the image dimension. how to return this object
    image.width = info.width;
    image.height = info.height;
    return image;
})
let metainfo = stream.pipe(metaReader)
```

Comment: it doesn't work since metaReader is asynchronous. therefore metainfo gets the initial value of dims (i.e undefined). also image.height doesn't work as image(variable) is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You could return the value dims and then interact with it in the next then
or you could just interact with those dimensions in the current one you have.

```
const metaReader = sharp()
metaReader
  .metadata()
  .then(info => {
    const dims = {width: info.width, height: info.height}
    // Interact with dims here
    // Or return it and interact in the next then
    return dims
  }).then(dims => {
   // or interact with the dimensions here.
  })
```

Comment: it doesn't work since metaReader is asynchronous. therefore metainfo gets the initial value of dims (i.e {})

Comment: It's unclear what you're doing then. What are you trying to do with metainfo and the stream? Any data you get in this async request will have to be used inside the then block since it's a promise. Updated the code snippet